# Javascript / HTML adding an image to center position on the mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, image, photo, onmouseclick

I want to print out a picture whenever the mouse is clicked on the screen.
This is my current Javascript and HTML code.  It only prints the h1, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```js
var image = document.getElementById("im"); // idenfitifes span eleme nt                                                                                                                                   
var roll = false; // to know the image is moving or not , intitally it is not moving state hence value is false                                                                                           
image.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false); // at starting image is in rest                                                                                                                        

function mouse_move(x) // funciton to move image with mouse                                                                                                                                               
{
    var newX = x.clientX; // copies mouse x position                                                                                                                                                      
    var newY = x.clientY; // copies mouse y position                                                                                                                                                      
    image.style.left = newY + "px"; // assigns latest mouse position to span (image)                                                                                                                      
    image.style.top = newX + "px";
}

function start(x) // span (image) starting no rolling mode                                                                                                                                                
{
    if(roll){ // when the mouse is moving                                                                                                                                                                 
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouse_move); // initiages image span move                                                                                                               
        roll = !roll;
        return;
    }
    roll = !roll; // when the mouse is not moving                                                                                                                                                         
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse_move, false);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title> Picture of Me! </title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1> HTML File to move image along with mouse movement. </h1>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="h5j.js">

  <span id="im">
    <img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/04/27/us/politics/00-trump-cand-page/00-trump-cand-page-mediumSquareAt3X.jpg" height="120" width="120"></img>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HI there and welcome. I am a bit confused about the title and what are you trying to achieve. Are you trying to create drag functionality to an image?

So when users click mouse down and move the mouse then the image should fallow, and then once they release the mouse then the image should stay where ever it was left off?

Comment: hello, not necessarily, I just want to place a picture wherever I click the mouse on the page

Answer (score 1):

You Use The AddEventListener Function Like This

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouse_move, false);
```

the syntax for addEventListener is:
addEventListener("Event Name", "Your Function name, the function you want to run after event happening")

when you need to run in the click event, you simply need to change Event name from "mousedown" to "click" , example:
document.addEventListener("click", mouse_move, false);

you have to use "click" event instead of "mousedown"
like:

`document.addEventListener("click", mouse_move, false);`

```
<code>
        var image = document.getElementById("im"); 
            var roll = false; 
           image.addEventListener("click", start, false); 
    
            function mouse_move(x) 
            {
                var newX = x.clientX; // copies mouse x position
                var newY = x.clientY; // copies mouse y position
                image.style.left = newX + "px";
                image.style.top = newY+ "px";
            }
    
            function start(x) // span (image) starting no rolling mode
            {
                if (roll) { // when the mouse is moving
                    document.removeEventListener("click", mouse_move); // initiages image span move
                    roll = !roll;
                    return;
                }
                roll = !roll; // when the mouse is not moving
    
            }
            document.addEventListener("click", mouse_move, false);
</code>
```

Comment: Yes OFC bro,  you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to get the image element by id, before the `DOM` has finished loading.

I would suggest one of the following:

1. Move the `<script>` tag to the bottom of the page between `</body>` and `</html>`
2. Add `defer` to the `<script>` tag, which will cause the script to be loaded after the DOM.
3. Move the first block of your JavaScript into a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener as shown below.

```js
var roll = false;
var image;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    image = document.getElementById("im");                                                                                      
    image.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);  
});
```

Comment: hello, okay this printed the picture I wanted however it is printed immediately and not wherever the use clicks

Comment: You would first need to set your `span` to `position:fixed` as shown in the below answer.
Then it should work. `fixed` allows the element to freely move around the screen as you want. (It does alot more than that but doesn't require more explanation here)